# How to run gui app from cron as root?

Tags: 11.10, cron, crontab

The following works in cron:

```
* *  * * *  non-root-user  export DISPLAY=:0.0; zenity --info
```

And displays a zenity dialog on non-root-user's desktop each minute.

But if I do the following:

```
* *  * * *  root  export DISPLAY=:0.0; zenity --info
```

it does not work - nothing is shown on 0.0 display. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does not worked for me. 3.5.0-17-generic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have run afoul of X-windows security! See `man Xsecurity`, `man xauth`, and `man xhost`, but in the short term, you can allow any UID running on your local system to have access to your X display by doing:

```
xhost +localhost
```

as your non-root UID from the session that has the display.

Comment: It would be resetted after reboot?

Comment: It would be reset by `xhost -localhost` or by exiting the `X` session that owns the $DISPLAY. Fixing things by a reboot is usually not necessary, and often doesn't work. It's not the Linux way.